# Datatables Translation don't works

Tags: laravel-4, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have got a [datatable](https://datatables.net/manual/i18n) using Datatables server-side. I have created and filled the table as shown below. Now I need to translate the datatable depending on the language , I found this example in the documentation :

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    language: {
        search: "Search in table:"
    }
} );
```

or loading translation :

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    language: {
        url: '/localisation/fr_FR.json'
    }
} );
```

But none of them works for me ! this is my code :

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>adress</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
</table>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable = $('#example').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "server-side-process",
            },

        "columns": [
                    { "data": "name" },
                    { "data": "adress" },
                ]
    } );

} );
```

Comment: In your code there's no "language" option. Where did you put it? Could you also show the contents/format of the `fr_FR.json` file? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: I put it in my code and it doesn't work , there is any error in the console

Comment: "language": {
            "search": "Search in table:"
        } ... don't works

Comment: See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/ufhfhha9/) where `language.search` works fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
var oTable = $('#example').DataTable({
    "language": {"url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/i18n/Spanish.json"},
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {...
```

https://datatables.net/plug-ins/i18n/

Answer (score 0):

Below is a working example of two datatables. One using default English and one loading French as per the documentation: https://datatables.net/reference/option/language

JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/invalidname/mro9h48u/2/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable = $('#example').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": false,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "https://run.mocky.io/v3/b99908b5-61f9-4d41-9292-deaa510f3d93",
            },

        "columns": [
                    { "data": "name" },
                    { "data": "adress" },
                ]
    } );
} );



$(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable = $('#exampleFR').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": false,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "https://run.mocky.io/v3/b99908b5-61f9-4d41-9292-deaa510f3d93",
            },
                 "language": {
                "url": "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.21/i18n/French.json"
            },
        "columns": [
                    { "data": "name" },
                    { "data": "adress" },
                ]
    } );
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<H1>
English table
</H1>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>adress</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
</table>
<hr>
<hr>
<H1>
French table
</H1>
<table id="exampleFR" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>adress</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
</table>
```